# Android - Crop an image programmatically

Tags: android, android-camera, crop

I've got an activity with a camera preview below an ImageSwitcher, as is shown in the iamge below.

[image]

As you can see, the camera preview (down) and the picture taken (up) does not correspond each other. What I want to do is to take a photo of what I'm exactly viewing in the preview OR crop automatically the picture taken to the same size of the camera preview.

Thanks in advance.